# Ender 5 Plus offset issue

Tags: homing, creality-ender-5

Me: Experienced coder, Entry level 3D print person.

Setup

- Ender 5 Plus
- Creality V2.2 Board
- BLTouch
- Marlin
- Titan Aero

Notes: Using a custom mount for the head and probe.

- Front Left Top is 0,0,0
- X/Y End Stops are at TOP REAR RIGHT

I am unable to find a configuration that sets the head to the center of the bed X Y after home

I have tried

- Max Min Offset
- probe to nozzle offset
- hotend offset
- moving the endstops
- changing the bedsize
- Setting G92 position 0 0 at the true 0 0
- setting center to 0 0
- setting front left edge to 0 0
- setting right rear to 360 360
- setting true center at 180 180
- ender 3 screen (to use menu to align)
- BTT-TFT35 Screen (to use menu to align)
- Marlin latest
- InsanityAutomation/Marlin Darwin
- Th3d Marlin latest
- Cura 4.4.1
- Cura Latast
- Octopi
- Console (setting params and values manually, EEPROM)

None of the above trials, either alone or combined in appropriate ways are centering the head to the bed after home.

The only way I can even move where the hotend ends up after home, is by changing `X_BED_SIZE` and `X_BED_SIZE` (still unable to use the specified area of the bed and center the head).

Comment: To center the head after homing enable `SAFE_HOMING` in your configuration. Note that front left **bottom** is (0, 0, 0). Setting boundaries using a probe is described in [How to set Z-probe boundary limits in firmware when using automatic bed leveling?](/q/8153/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Z-probe boundary limits in firmware when using automatic bed leveling?](/q/8153/).